# Simultaneous Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scanning on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, network-scan

I have developed the code for continuous and simultaneous Wi-Fi ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305219/wi-fi-scanning-without-broadcast-receiver/6305365)) and Bluetooth ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285580/how-to-periodically-scan-for-bluetooth-devices-on-android)) scanning. I found out that when both scannings are activated then the number of Wi-Fi ScanResults drops approximately by half. Can I assume that it could be the interference issue?

Answer (score 0):

Their signals interfere with each other if they are in the same wave range.  It looks like this is the case.  See this post for the wifi/bluetooth GHz ranges; it may also provide you with additional information you are looking for:
[Bluetooth protocol over wifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061110/bluetooth-protocol-over-wifi)